# Set up Ingress on Minikube with the NGINX Ingress Controller according to Kubernetes documentation

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

"[Create an Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress)" is not working.

Part A: Verify that the Ingress controller is directing traffic is not working.
Part B: Add external IP address as reported by minikube is not working.
Also, Tried creating minikube tunnel for service example-ingress in vain.

Please refer to the terminal output(s) for details:

**Terminal Output 1 Part A - Verify that the Ingress controller is directing traffic**

```
Last login: Tue Oct 24 19:11:06 on console
% sw_vers                                                                               
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.0
BuildVersion:       23A344
% arch                                                                                  
arm64
% docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35
 Version:           24.0.2
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.4
 Git commit:        cb74dfc
 Built:             Thu May 25 21:51:16 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.21.1 (114176)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.2
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.4
  Git commit:       659604f
  Built:            Thu May 25 21:50:59 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
% kubectl version --output=yaml
clientVersion:
  buildDate: "2023-10-18T11:33:16Z"
  compiler: gc
  gitCommit: a8a1abc25cad87333840cd7d54be2efaf31a3177
  gitTreeState: clean
  gitVersion: v1.28.3
  goVersion: go1.20.10
  major: "1"
  minor: "28"
  platform: darwin/arm64
kustomizeVersion: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3

The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
% kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null
% minikube version
minikube version: v1.31.2
commit: fd7ecd9c4599bef9f04c0986c4a0187f98a4396e
% minikube start
  minikube v1.31.2 on Darwin 14.0 (arm64)
✨  Automatically selected the docker driver
  Using Docker Desktop driver with root privileges
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.27.4 preload ...
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v18-v1...:  327.74 MiB / 327.74 MiB  100.00% 2.23 Mi
    > gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase...:  404.50 MiB / 404.50 MiB  100.00% 2.57 Mi
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB) ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.27.4 on Docker 24.0.4 ...
    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...
    ▪ Configuring RBAC rules ...
  Configuring bridge CNI (Container Networking Interface) ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
% minikube addons enable ingress
  ingress is an addon maintained by Kubernetes. For any concerns contact minikube on GitHub.
You can view the list of minikube maintainers at: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/OWNERS
  After the addon is enabled, please run "minikube tunnel" and your ingress resources would be available at "127.0.0.1"
    ▪ Using image registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.8.1
    ▪ Using image registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20230407
    ▪ Using image registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20230407
  Verifying ingress addon...
  The 'ingress' addon is enabled
% kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-v4vnj        0/1     Completed   0          46s
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-dw4xw         0/1     Completed   0          46s
ingress-nginx-controller-7799c6795f-7fb9w   0/1     Running     0          46s
% kubectl create deployment web --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
deployment.apps/web created
% kubectl expose deployment web --type=NodePort --port=8080
service/web exposed
% kubectl get service web
NAME   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
web    NodePort   10.98.92.201   <none>        8080:31242/TCP   30s
% minikube service web --url
http://127.0.0.1:49557
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
^C%                                                                                                                                                             
% wget https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml
--2023-10-24 19:39:16--  https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml
Resolving k8s.io (k8s.io)... 34.107.204.206
Connecting to k8s.io (k8s.io)|34.107.204.206|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://kubernetes.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml [following]
--2023-10-24 19:39:17--  https://kubernetes.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml
Resolving kubernetes.io (kubernetes.io)... 147.75.40.148
Connecting to kubernetes.io (kubernetes.io)|147.75.40.148|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 390 [application/x-yaml]
Saving to: ‘example-ingress.yaml’

example-ingress.yaml                    100%[===============================================================================>]     390  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-10-24 19:39:18 (372 MB/s) - ‘example-ingress.yaml’ saved [390/390]

% cat example-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 8080%                                                                                                                                 % kubectl apply -f example-ingress.yaml
ingress.networking.k8s.io/example-ingress created
% kubectl get ingress
NAME              CLASS   HOSTS              ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   nginx   hello-world.info   192.168.49.2   80      58s
% curl --resolve "hello-world.info:80:$( minikube ip )" -i http://hello-world.info
curl: (28) Failed to connect to hello-world.info port 80 after 75000 ms: Couldn't connect to server
%
```

**Terminal Output 1 Part B - Add external IP address as reported by minikube**

```
% sudo vim /etc/hosts
Password:
% cat /etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
172.17.0.15 hello-world.info
# End of section
% open http://hello-world.info/
% curl http://hello-world.info/
curl: (28) Failed to connect to hello-world.info port 80 after 75010 ms: Couldn't connect to server
%
```

**Terminal Output 2:** - Created minikube tunnel for service example-ingress in vain

```
Last login: Tue Oct 24 19:14:56 on ttys000
% curl http://127.0.0.1:49557
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-548f6458b5-gqllc
% sudo minikube tunnel
Password:
✅  Tunnel successfully started

  NOTE: Please do not close this terminal as this process must stay alive for the tunnel to be accessible ...

❗  The service/ingress example-ingress requires privileged ports to be exposed: [80 443]
  sudo permission will be asked for it.
  Starting tunnel for service example-ingress.
```